# Is It Possible to Use UIImage Inside an Array of Objects?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I made a struct `Question`

```
struct Question {

let imageView: UIImage
let textField: String
let textField2: String }
```

class `SpellingViewController`

```
class SpellingViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var theImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var theInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var progBar: UIProgressView!

var spellingScore: Int64 = 0
var questionNum = 0

let question = [
    Question2(imageView: UIImage(named: "BeardQ")!, textField: "Beard", textField2: "beard"),
    Question2(imageView: UIImage(named: "CastleQ")!, textField: "Castle", textField2: "castle"),
    Question2(imageView: UIImage(named: "CloudQ")!, textField: "Cloud", textField2: "cloud"),
    Question2(imageView: UIImage(named: "Elephant")!, textField: "Elephant", textField2: "elephant"),
    Question2(imageView: UIImage(named: "RainQ")!, textField: "Rain", textField2: "rain")
] }
```

As you can see, I created this array and placed the UIImages inside it along with the textField and textField2. Simply, I'm gonna display an image to the user and I'm gonna take an input that describes the image and examine if it matches textField and textField2 or not. While running the simulator, I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7f9987017e80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Is it because I'm using UIImage inside an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you are getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7f9987017e80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

It is almost certain that you have a UIView class in your interface somewhere with a property `imageView` which is not valid. I suggest doing a multi-file search for the string `imageView`. Set the search to whole words, case sensitive. It finds strings inside Storyboards as well as source files, so you should be able to find it that way.

Comment: Yup! You are absolutely right. When I checked the storyboard and deleted the outlet in my VC, I discovered that I, unfortunately, connected the wrong imageView to this VC. Thanks a lot for your tips and help!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you should accept it

Answer (score 1):

Your `Question2` class is not a subclass of `UIViewController` Or `UIView`, so it doesn’t make sense to create `@IBOutlet` s in it.

Outlets are set when a view controller or view is created from a storyboard or nib file. You aren’t doing that, so there is no way those outlets will have a value.

It doesn't make sense to be creating multiple instances of views and putting them in an array anyway for your purpose.

You should use a `Question` struct and then supply an instance of that struct to a view controller that can display it.

```swift
struct Question {
   let image: UIImage
   let txt: String
   let txt2: String
}

let question = [
    Question(img: UIImage(named: "BeardQ")!, txt: "Beard", txt2: "beard"),
    Question(img: UIImage(named: "CastleQ")!, txt: "Castle", txt2: "castle"),
    Question(img: UIImage(named: "CloudQ")!, txt: "Cloud", txt2: "cloud"),
    Question(img: UIImage(named: "Elephant")!, txt: "Elephant", txt2: "elephant"),
    Question(img: UIImage(named: "RainQ")!, txt: "Rain", txt2: "rain")
] }
```

The view controller will have the outlets and you will assign to the content of those outlets based on the `Question` that is provided to it.

The exception regarding an undefined key shows that your storyboard or nib has specified a class of `UIView` (Which doesn’t have any outlet properties) rather than whatever subclass you have created with those IBOutlet properties

Comment: No, the OPs Question class is just a class object, not a subclass of UIViewController. It has @IBOutlets, which does not make sense. Your solution of storing the image as a property of the object **does** make sense, and seems like the right solution. (Voted.)

Comment: I created the struct and supplied the instance to the VC, however, I'm still getting the same error, which is confusing a little bit.

Comment: @DuncanC, thanks.  I saw the outlets and assumed it was a view controller.

Comment: @AhmedAlFailakawi edit your question to show your new code, including the line on which it is crashing. Usually that error message means you have an IBOutlet/IBAction in your storyboard that points to target that doesn't have a matching property.

Comment: @DuncanC The error is a run time error it's saying **__pthread_kill** with a given address. I made sure that the IBOutlets are correctly connected from the storyboard to the VC. **Question has been updated**

Comment: In your question you quote the full error message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7f9987017e80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". That is the important bit.